# Dynamic PHP Layout

Tags: php

I am attempting to create a dynamic layout for my website.  I previously was successful in making an example but now that I have moved over to codeignitor I am having trouble converting the logic as it were.  Below is a photo of the layout and the code i used to make it.

[image: layout]

```
    //Picture Layout Start              
    if ($i == 0 || $i == 12 || $i == 24 || $i == 36 || $i == 48) {  ?>  

<div id="product_big"><a href="/shop/product/<?php echo $name;  ?>/<?php echo $type; ?>/#product"><img src="/crop.php?h=462&w=462&f=<?php echo $poly;?>" title="<?php echo $full; ?>" alt="<?php echo $full; ?>" style="border:none;"></a></div>                                

    <?php }elseif ($i == 6 || $i == 18 || $i == 30 || $i == 42 || $i == 54) { ?>            
<div id="product_big2"><a href="/shop/product/<?php echo $name;  ?>/<?php echo $type; ?>/#product"><img src="/crop.php?h=462&w=462&f=<?php echo $poly;?>" title="<?php echo $full; ?>" alt="<?php echo $full; ?>" style="border:none;"></a></div>

    <?php }elseif ($i == 3 || $i == 4 || $i == 5 || $i == 9 || $i == 10 || $i == 11 || $i == 15 || $i == 16 || $i == 17 || $i == 21 || $i == 22 || $i == 23 || $i == 27 || $i == 28 || $i == 29 || $i == 33 || $i == 34 || $i == 35 || $i == 39 || $i == 40 || $i == 41 || $i == 45 || $i == 46 || $i == 47) { ?>           

<div class="products3"><a href="/shop/product/<?php echo $name;  ?>/<?php echo $type; ?>/#product"><img src="/crop.php?h=225&w=225&f=<?php echo $poly;?>" title="<?php echo $full; ?>" alt="<?php echo $full; ?>" style="border:none;"></a></div>   

    <?php }elseif ($i == 7 || $i == 8 || $i == 19 || $i == 20 || $i == 31 || $i == 32 || $i == 43 || $i == 44){ ?>          

    <div class="products2"><a href="/shop/product/<?php echo $name;  ?>/<?php echo $type; ?>/#product"><img src="/crop.php?h=225&w=225&f=<?php echo $poly;?>" title="<?php echo $full; ?>" alt="<?php echo $full; ?>" style="border:none;"></a></div>
    <?php }else{  ?>            

    <div class="products"><a href="/shop/product/<?php echo $name;  ?>/<?php echo $type; ?>/#product"><img src="/crop.php?h=225&w=225&f=<?php echo $poly;?>" title="<?php echo $full; ?>" alt="<?php echo $full; ?>" style="border:none;"></a></div>

<?php   } //end layout if }//end for loop ?>
```

The code I made is limited as it is fixed.  I looked around for ways to create dynamic layouts like those of pinterest but they did not seem to apply very well to this issue.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you are having issues with the layout because of PHP, you are probably using too much HTML echos in PHP, while you could include HTML views. It would also help to have a clearer code ...

Comment: not sure I understand what you're after, but a quick way to clean up the spaghetti you've posted would be to do something like `$product_big = array(0,12,24,36,48);$product_big2 = array(6,18,30,42,54);etc...` then in your `IF/ELSE` sequence you could do `if(in_array($i, $product_big){}elseif(in_array($i, $product_big2)){}...etc...`

Comment: I know its a messy code that is why it is hard for me to use the more friendly codeignitor.  Would a series of foreach statements make this possible?

Comment: Your statement made all the difference as i was able to rethink the approach the second time versus that messy code i posted.  My solution utilized a set of arrays like you mentioned and not only is it cleaner but works even better. Thanks again though i am unable to mark this as solved.  Thank you MLeFevre.